# OnLocation change with google maps api in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using google maps marker for my current location i'm able to retrieve current latitude and longitude locations but how can i get the updated location when ever it is changed. I wrote a separate class for tracking current location and called the class in main Activity where i used googleApi client for displaying marker now the problem is how can i change the marker whenever the location is changed in this main activity class

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: You set requestLocationChange listener and onLocationChange you can update your marker..

Comment: onLocationChange is written in another class i have used the example GPSTracker. Here getting location details is given GPSTracker class and this class object is called in MainAcitivity. map object is also declared in Activity

Answer (score 1):

As you are tracking your location from different class. you can create your own listener for that to listen location change in main class

first create location change listener

```
public interface LocationListener {
    public void onLocationReceived(Location location);
}
```

implement this listener in your call like that

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implement LocationListener{
     public void onLocationReceived(Location location){
     // update your map pin here 
    }
}
```

when call your location class from mainactivity pass a listener of location change to that class 
like that

```
LocationClass class = new LocationClass(this);
```

in LocationClass add a costructor

```
LocationListener listener;
public LocationClass (LocationListener listener){
this.listener = listener;
}
```

now whenever you get new location call this function

```
this.listener.onLocationReceived(location);
```

It will work in your case.

your have other option like you can implement google's location listener in your own activity

Answer (score 0):

@user1335906 You can refer below link to get location updates frequently...

```
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates
```

1) First of all you've to connect with google service using below method:

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
```

2) After successful connection to google service, setup for your locationRequest object using below method:

```
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1500); // this will give location update after 1500 miliseconds, set it according to your requirement
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.5f); // this will calculate distance between your previous and current location, if it is greater then 0.5 meter this method will be triggered.
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); // set location accuracy level as per app requirement.
}
```

2) You will get frequent location updates in below method:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
// Here you will get your current location every time when it gets changed,
// put log here and see current location updates
}
```

So give it a try and let me know if you are not getting it...

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you add marker you can have the reference to the your marker.

```
Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(...)
```

So when you receive a location change then just simply change it's position

```
marker.setPosition(new LatLng(...));
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(...));
```

This will animate the map and moving to the location change but marker will not animated. If distance is long the marker is jumping from one place to another. So if you want to animate marker as well then use ValueAnimator to animate the marker.